# will have said VS. would say

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, auxiliary-verbs

ex) *I can't think why he was willing to say that it was my fault.*

Now, for the purpose of making a sentence to have the same meaning of the example sentence, I would like to use modal auxiliary verb *'will'*.

*I can't think why he will have said that it was my fault.*

Is this sentence a grammatically correct equivalet of the example sentence?

Again, for the same purpose above, I would like to use modal auxiliary verb *'would'*.

*I can't think why he would say that it was my fault.*

Is this sentence a grammatically correct equivalet of the example sentence?

Comment: I'm not going to close-hammer this question, but to my mind, "Is this sentence I made up a correct equivalent to this other sentence?" falls under "proof-reading". CV only if you agree

Comment: @gotube: I think IF a question presents us with a good opportunity to examine a feature of English that often perplexes learners, we shouldn't be too keen to close it just because it has *aspects* of proofreading. I'm pretty sure the OP here has conflated modal ***would*** with the state of being "willing = agreeable, with consent".

Comment: @gotube: I don't know the meanings of the verb "close-hammer" and the abbreviated word "CV" . Please tell me the meanings of them.

Comment: @gonjuyi "CV" means "close vote". Normally, if five people vote to close a question, it is closed, but because I'm a Moderator on this site (I have the little "♦" next to my name), if I close vote a question, it closes immediately. I'm informally calling this power a "close hammer".

Comment: @gotube: Thank you for your helpful comment.

Comment: You can't just substitute one modal for another and expect them to have the same meaning, especially if you're changing the tense! Does your native language think that sentences mean the same thing no matter what words are in them?

Answer (score 0):

I think OP is confusing "being willing" with the modal ***would*** (used to reference a hypothetical situation).

> 1: *I can't think why he **will** have said that it was my fault* <=== INVALID

> 2: *I can't think why he **was** willing to accuse me*
> 3: *I can't think why he **would have been** willing to accuse me*
> 4: *I can't think why he **would be** willing to accuse me*

Note that both #3 and #4 can be used to mean exactly the same as #2, but #4 can also be used to refer to a possible *future* accusation<sup>1</sup>...

> 3a: *I can't think why he **would have been** willing to accuse me in court yesterday*
> 4a: *I can't think why he **would be** willing to accuse me in court tomorrow*

Also note that he might be *forced to **unwillingly*** accuse me, so we might not want to mention "willingness" at all...

> 3b: *I can't think why he **would have accused** me in court yesterday*
> 4b: *I can't think why he **would accuse** me in court tomorrow*

Note that 3b above would often imply that he *didn't* accuse me, but it can also be used even if he *did* accuse me - OR if I don't actually *know* whether he accused me or not (same as with 4b, where I can't know for certain whether he will or won't accuse me *tomorrow*).

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that #4 (without "tomorrow") could also be used as a "timeless" reference to the possibility of him accusing me in the past OR the future (or indeed, in any hypothetical scenario unrelated to past / present / future).

Comment: In my post, I used 'will' to show that sb is willing to do sth. According to Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary sixth edtion, 'will' can be used for showing that sb is willing to do sth. For example, "I'll check this letter for you, if you want.", "They won't lend us any more money.", "He wouldn't come-he said he was too busy.", "We said we would keep them." Further, In my post, I used 'would' simply as the past form of 'will'.

Comment: So, in my post, 'would' has the same meaning with 'would' in the following example. "He was very ill at that time, but he would go."

Comment: Frankly speaking, I don't know the meaning of 'would' in your post. Why is "I can't think why he was willing to accuse me." equal to either "I can't think why he would have been willing to accuse me." or "I can't think why he would be willing to accuse me."? Please tell me the dictionary meaning of 'would' in your post.

Comment: @gonjuyi: Like I said, you're confusing modal ***would*** with ***to be willing***. But can you not see that *I can't think why he was willing to accuse me* effectively ***entails*** the fact that he ***did*** accuse me, whereas neither version of *I can't think why he would **have been willing / would be willing** to accuse me* forces that interpretation. And as previously pointed out, the ***...why he would be willing...*** version can refer to a [possible] *future* accusation as well as a [possible] *past* or *hypothetical* accusation. Plus he might accuse me ***unwillingly***.

Comment: Note that *He was very ill at that time, but he would go* (he *insisted* on going) is barely English. Avoid it.

Comment: 1. Then, Does "I can't think why he was willing to accuse me" imply that he really did accuse me? Whereas doesn't either version of "I can't think why he would have been willing / would be willing to accuse me" imply that he really did accuse me?

Comment: *I can't think why he was willing to accuse me* doesn't just ***imply*** (suggest) that he really did accuse me. It ***entails*** that he did (you can't even *say* it unless you know he did it). But honestly, you should stop thinking about "being willing" in this context, because it's obviously just confusing you (he might have been *willing* to make the accusation, *but didn't in fact do so*). Just get your head around the possible meanings of *I can't think why he would **accuse / have accused** me* first. You can think about "being willing" *much* later, if at all.

Comment: Yes, *I can't think why he would accuse me in court yesterday* is syntactically fine. In principle it's a relatively unlikely thing to say compared to the Perfect version *...why he would **have accused** me yesterday* - but purely because it's *simpler*, some people would say it anyway. There are subtle implications with both versions as regards whether the speaker knows / believes that an accusation was (or might feasibly in the future *be*) made, but I think you should ignore those for now. Native Anglophones won't all agree on those implications anyway, which are highly context-specific.

Comment: 2. I think "I can't think why he would have been willing to accuse me yesterday" can be paraphrased that "I suppose he was willing to accuse me yesterday, but I have no evidence for that supposition". Is this paraphrasing correct?

Comment: *Please,* stop thinking about being willing! You're just going round in circles! You need to understand ***modal*** "would" first! Note that ***I can't think why...*** and ***I suppose...*** have no meaningful connection in the current context.

Comment: O.K. Thank you for your advice, but 1. How about "His income was still small, but she would marry him" and "At last she put her arms round the top, as far as they would go"? Are these sentences barely English also?

Comment: 2. "I can't think why he would have accused me in court yesterday" Can this sentence be paraphrased to "It's possible that he accused me in court yesterday, but, if he did, I don't know why."?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use "understand" instead of "think" here.

The second example above is incorrect, "will have" is an auxiliary verb that changes the tense of the sentence, and is unrelated to "willing."

But you can say:

**I can't understand why he was willing to say that it was my fault.**

or

**I can't understand why he would say that it was my fault.**

Those are both fine.

"Don't know" is very common here as well, as in:

**I don't know why he would say that it was my fault.**

Answer (score -1):

> I can't think why he will have said that it was my fault.

You could say this but it sounds clunky.  Meaning, you're confused but know the definite event will happen.

> I can't think why he would say that it was my fault.

This is much better.  'would' brings an ambiguity in tense that matches the state of 'can't think'.

The example and two alternatives don't really mean the same thing.  'willing' means he was amiable or convinced to blame you while 'will' and 'would' mean he just did it.

> He will testify against you.

vs

> He's willing to testify against you if we offer him a deal.

Comment: I don't think ***will*** can ever truly be "valid" in this context, regardless of whether the possible accusation is in the past *(why he **would have** accused me [in court yesterday])* OR the future *(why he **would** accuse me [in court tomorrow])*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Which is why I point out specifically the two different meanings because OP's question is actually about 'will'.  I hope you didn't downvote because you'd be wrong to do so.

Comment: But you say *You **could** say this but it sounds clunky.* I don't think you *can* say that! And even if you could, it would have nothing to do with being "willing".

Comment: @Johns-305: In my post, I used 'will' to show that sb is willing to do sth. According to Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary sixth edtion, 'will' can be used for showing that sb is willing to do sth. For example, "I'll check this letter for you, if you want.", "They won't lend us any more money.", "He wouldn't come-he said he was too busy.", "We said we would keep them." Further, In my post, I used 'would' simply as the past form of 'will'.

Comment: So, in my post, 'would' has the same meaning with 'would' in the following example. "He was very ill at that time, but he would go."

Comment: And yet can't the example and two alternatives really mean the same thing?

Comment: @gonjuyi 'Will' is usually a definitive statement.  "I will testify."  'Would' conveys ambiguity or a condition.  "I would testify if offered a deal."  In that case, 'would' is not a past form.

Comment: @Johns-305: I agree 'would' is not a past form in the sentence of "I would testify if offered a deal". Further, I don't insist 'would' be a past form of 'will' in any sentence. I'm just using 'would' as a past form of 'will'(to have the meaning of 'be willing to') in the sentence of "I can't think why he would say that it was my fault".

Comment: Please see the following link. Cambridge Dictionary also says 'will' has one meaning of 'being willing to' and I am considering 'will' to have that meaning in the sentence of "I can't think why he will have said that it was my fault". https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/will

Comment: Another site where to be able to know 'will' has the meaning of 'being willing to' https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/will-would

Comment: @gonjuyi I'm familiar with a dictionary.  But you have to understand spoken language is interpreted differently than the wonks write down.  "I will testify" is a commitment, willing or under duress.  "I would testify." means you're willing under some circumstances.